# Do you lose rep every time you downvote?

Tags: support, reputation, downvoting

I've noticed that I lose 1 rep for every downvote that I do, even if I leave a comment to explain. Is this supposed to be happening? I thought that the rep penalty was only for if you downvote without leaving a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not commenting that makes a difference, but the *type* of content that you are downvoting.  Downvoting **answers** always costs you 1 rep.  Downvoting **questions** doesn't reduce your rep at all.

This help center page covers this and more: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)